# sed command not working only for 1 scenario

Tags: unix, sh

I have this sed command line in my UNIX shell script to append the variable value to the existing line in a file.

```
sed "s/.*/&$OptionalCols/" header_scrubbed_vendor_list.dat \
    >>final_header_scrubbed_vendor_list_${TODAY}.dat
```

where the `OptionalCols` value is fetched from below

```
OptionalCols=`head -1 ${INDIR}Direct_Target_List_*.dat |cut -d'|' -f 19-48`
```

The appending task is working perfectly fine for all. but it is not working only for below one.

And 1st line in Direct_Target_List_*.dat file is

```
CID|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|Suffix|Specialty|AddressLine1|AddressLine2|City|State|ZipCode|Phone|Fax|MENumber|NPINumber|EmailAddress|StateLicenseNumber|GSKBrandPAR|ProfessionalDesignatio|Segment Name |GLP-User Flag|Tanzeum Action Group|Tanzeum See-status|Total_Access_042014to032015|SF_Access_042014to032015|SF_access_012015to032015|Received Samples|Tanzeum Engagers|Tanzeum Writers|NRx_201410to201503|TRx_201410to201503|DM_BRC_dont_use|Email_DMD_Match|CT_Mayo_Match|CT_FPN_Match|CT_IMN_Match|CT_Cons_Match|T/C|Group|Email_Segments|DM_Segments|Alerts_Segments
```

The error am getting is

> sed: command garbled: s/.*/&ProfessionalDesignatio|Segment Name
>   |GLP-User Flag|Tanzeum Action Group|Tanzeum
>   See-status|Total_Access_042014to032015|SF_Access_042014to032015|SF_access_012015to032015|Received
>   Samples|Tanzeum Engagers|Tanzeum
>   Writers|NRx_201410to201503|TRx_201410to201503|DM_BRC_dont_use|Email_DMD_Match|CT_Mayo_Match|CT_FPN_Match|CT_IMN_Match|CT_Cons_Match|T/C|Group|Email_Segments|DM_Segments|Alerts_Segments/

Do anybody have idea why this is happenning?

Comment: When header_scrubbed_vendor_list.dat only has 1 line, you can skip using sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash in `T/C` is likely being considered the delimiter. It's kind of tricky to see, so here is an extract:

```
...CT_Cons_Match|T/C|Group...
```

You can have sed use a different delimiter. Choose one that's guaranteed not to be in the input. For example:

```
sed -e 's#regex#replacement#'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a different separator for the `s` command.  The `/` in the replacement is interpreted as the end of the command, and the following `C|Group|Email_Segments|...` makes no sense to the interpreter.

Either delimit your substitution with something you know won't be in the variable  - e.g. `!` here:

```
sed -e "s!\$!$OptionalCols!" infile >>outfile
```

or massage the variable to replace `/` with `\/` when substituting:

```
sed -e "s/\$/${OptionalCols//\//\\\/}/" infile >>outfile
```

or, if that's hard to read, a combination of both:

```
sed -e "s!\$!${OptionalCols//!/\\!}!" infile >>outfile
```

(I've also changed `s/.*/&.../` to `s/$/.../` to reduce the workload).